# Strange response from a HTTP server

Tags: command-line, http, tcp, https, hosts

I noticed an unfamiliar device when scanning my local wireless network. It had two open (listening?) TCP ports; `TCP/80` (`http`?) & `TCP/443` (`https`?).

In an effort to identify the unfamiliar device; I exercised some basic banner-grabbing techniques, which provided some strange feedback:

```
root@localhost:~# telnet 10.1.1.28 80
Trying 10.1.1.28...
Connected to 10.1.1.28.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
@Q�0�njs-k��`Y���s��N��E2R�S������d���aw��
s�Y�/u"�`QN���I�eRA~W

Connection closed by foreign host.


root@localhost:~# telnet 10.1.1.28 80
Trying 10.1.1.28...
Connected to 10.1.1.28.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

Connection closed by foreign host.


root@localhost:~# telnet 10.1.1.28 80
Trying 10.1.1.28...
Connected to 10.1.1.28.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
"�))!���]D�7�ב�����┴�IL&�┬��#�-�zp�,o�������c��D����ל]�h����
                                                                @�.GLMC��2{���

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

What are these strange responses?

Comment: Your request headers are incomplete, by the way. The `Host` is mandatory in HTTP 1.1.